# How to get videos from rss feed entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, rss, feedjira, metainspector

I am trying to get videos(urls) from feed entry url.

I am using Feedjira and MetaInspector in my application to fetch and store articles along with images. Now I want to store videos of articles if any. Can anyone please tell me what could be the best possible ways to store videos from articles

Thank you.

Comment: You want to store the video file? As in rip the video stream and save it somewhere else?

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer No I want to get the Video URL so that using that url I can play the same video from my Android App without storing in my system. will it be possible?

Comment: I'm confused, are you asking how to find the video urls using Feedjira and MetaInspector, how best to store a list of video urls, or how to play them from an Android application?

Comment: @SomeSchmo I would like to get all video urls from a feed article and store the best video url in my database. How can I achieve this in rails

Comment: make a cron job. fetch the rss, crawl over it, and save every video url found.

Answer (score 2):

I do this in my project to save all the url found from rss feeds

```
Source.all.each do |source|
  feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(source.url)
  feed.entries.each do |entry|
    unless Link.exists? url: entry.url
      Link.create!(title: entry.title,
        url: entry.url)
    end
  end
end
```

in my snippet, I only save the url and title, for videos you just need to add `entry.video`,

you can see all the entry tag from `feed.entries` object or from the rss given.

and If you want to add another attributes, ex: `media:thumbnail` you could add this code before calling `fetch_and_parse` but you need to call it once not everytime you call `fetch_and_parse` to avoid memory leak

```
Feedjira::Feed.add_common_feed_entry_element("media:thumbnail", :value => :url, :as => :pic)
```

then you could do `entry.pic` to get the thumbnail url

Comment: I have tried the same but I am getting NoMethodError: undefined method `video' for #<Feedjira::Parser::RSSEntry:0x007f07f414ba60>  when I run entry.video and also Link is not defined.

Comment: maybe entry.video is doesnt exist, could u share the entry object? like `Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse('your rss url').entries.first`

Link is my model where I save the url/title data.

Comment: @icimelt I am using Feedjira for saving entries and images and everything is working fine. Now I want to get video urls from feed entries. I am not sure how to start on this as different feeds supporting different approchaed to embed videos in the articles. So Can you tell me how can we get a generic approach on this.

Comment: It should the same as you get the images and everything, as long as there is entry.object you can get it, you only need to examine, the fields in entries object that feedjira give. is there any video url, what is the field name. undefined method 'video' means feedjira doesnt found any rss <video> tag.

Comment: my `feed.entries.first` give me this `@title, @summary, @url, @entry_id, @published` If i do `feed.entires.video` of course I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'video'`

Comment: Yes I am not getting any video method from feed.entries with this can I conclude that we can't get any video information using feedjira

Comment: `feed.entries.first.try(:video) rescue nil` , it will give you nil if there is no video

Comment: Actually it will work if there is a direct video tag within that entry. but it wont work if video is embeded in a different way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150058/discussion-between-icemelt-and-anusha).